# what is the difference between "going to" and "will"?

Tags: difference, will-vs-going-to

what is the main difference between **going to and will**.  Why we use **going to** when **will** is of the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

A very confusing concept. Both refer to **future**
There is a slight difference between them but in most cases they are used with no difference in meaning.Both can be used for making predictions.
**For example**
*I think it will rain tomorrow = I think it is going to rain tomorrow*

- **Will** RAPID DECISION
- **Going to** PRIOR PLAN